# Woocommerce how to move the product tabs before the short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I move the product description tabs before the short description on my product page in WooCommerce?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );
```

But I need to appear higher on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code. You still keep the following that change the tabs location.

**The number associated with each hook basically sets the priority of execution. Lower the number, higher the priority of execution.**

[Reference](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/reorder-content-woocommerce-product-page/)

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
```